# What is the most proper way to add -ing to acronyms?

Tags: punctuation, orthography, hyphenation, acronyms

Sometimes acronyms represent actions. For example, a Super Smash Bros. player may be said to be "[DI-ing](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Directional_influence)" (Directional influencing).

In these situations, what would be the best-established style to use? Sometimes acronyms are so long that simply spelling everything out is extremely unwieldly. In the case of *DI-ing*, I find that in many fonts it can be read as "dling" if it's spelled without a hyphen, i.e. DIing. For this reason, I assume that including the hyphen is the preferred way to do things when spelling it out or rephrasing it would otherwise be unacceptable, but I can't think of any discussion on this topic or style guide rules.

Comment: This question is asking for sources and the best practice. The answers in the older question appear to be subjective and offer no supporting evidence. For these reasons I've cast my reopen vote.

Comment: I am voting to reopen because the alleged duplicate has no clear guidance or answer.

Comment: It's also a duplicate of  [Using present participle and past tense of an acronym](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/345050/using-present-participle-and-past-tense-of-an-acronym) - the leading answer doesn't have many votes but seems accurate.

Comment: See also [past tense of RSVP](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33786/past-tense-of-rsvp), [LOL as verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212929/lol-spelling-double-l-or-single-l-for-lolled-lolling-vs-loled-loling), [RDP as a verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/305824/using-rdp-as-a-verb), and more. There doesn't appear to be a clear answer, and asking the same question over and over again isn't good practice.

Comment: If I get a vote to re-open my own question, I would like to vote as such for all the reasons already cited by others, especially in my skepticism towards accepting the brief no-hyphen answer provided in "Using present participle and past tense of an acronym," and in acknowledging that the RSVP, LOL, and RDP answers don't address -ing. Also, thank you for fixing my tags and adding markup text, Mari.